# Deploy Spring Boot Application on Google App Engine

Tags: spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Google Standard App Engine has a limit of roughly 35MB for its application deployment.
I wanted to deploy a Spring Boot based application to GAE, but just by referencing

```
   dependencies {
       implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
       implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'

       runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'                                      
   }
```

the app already exceeds 40MB. Is there a way to let App Engine know to fetch these files during run time rather than compiling them into one big war file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are not limiting file size to 35mb. We still deployed over 100mb projects.
[image]

But one thing, Make sure you are using

```
App Engine Standard Version
```

instead of App Engine Flexible Version

Comment: It was indeed Flexible Version. I specified an app.yaml not knowing that I would have needed a appengine-web.xml for the Standard Version. I just wrote a NodeJs Server for which you use app.yaml hence the confusion. The Plugin generated an app.yaml on its own overwriting my configurations and deploying it as a Flexible Version. Thank you for your help! It works now!

Answer (score 0):

The 32MB limitation is [only for individual files](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas#Deployments).

The old way of deploying (appcfg.sh) worked over the uncompressed war file and maven (`mvn clean package appengine:deploy`) uploads individual files so none of both ways can hit a limitation because of the 'whole war size'

See this spring-boot app that I am playing with. I've just added a dummy 23MB file to it and everything works:
[image]

What I am trying to say is that I am not familiar with gradle but I would find it hard to believe they've made such a mistake on the newest deployment tool.

Have you really hit this limitation? In such a case, can you share the command you use to deploy and the exact error?

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.

Comment: I have been using the plugin com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-gradle-plugin:1.+ I am still a little bit unfamiliar with Gradle as well. I will play with this a little more and get back to you!

Comment: I just had to switch to Standard Environment. So you were right too it is possible.